# Access csv data from htttp request in ruby

Tags: ruby, api, csv

I'm trying to access the csv data, which I recive if I make a http-request.
I don't save it to a csv file, so I save it to the variable.
Let's say this is the response I get, how can I print food?

```
uuid,event_id,category
12,1,food
13,2,cars
```

And this is the part of the ruby code which is important.
That's something I found, but it was originally used with a file, so it doesn't work.

```
csvdata = request(action,parameter)
@data_hash = {}
CSV.foreach(csvdata) do |row|
  uuid, event_id, category = row
  @data_hash[uuid] = event_id
end
```

Do I really need files for that or is there a easy way I can access the values?

**Update**

```
CSV.parse(csvdata,data = Hash.new) do |row|
  puts data
end
```

The hash should look  like this so I can use the column names

```
{"uuid" => "12,13", "event_id" => "323,3243", "category" => "food,cars"}
```

Comment: Is that a single string?

Comment: It comes back in csv format, but I write it in a simple variable so I don't know if it's still in csv.

Answer (score 1):

```
csv_data = Hash.new{|k, v| k[v] = []}
CSV.parse(csv_string, headers: true) do |row|
  row.each{|k, v| csv_data[k] << v}
end
csv_data = Hash[csv_data.map{|k, v| [k, v.join(",")]}]
```

> Update after specification Requested output.

Comment: @aha364636 Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
csvdata = request(action,parameter)
@data_hash = {}
CSV.parse(csvdata, headers: true) do |row|
  @data_hash[row['uuid']] = row['event_id']
end

@data_hash
# => {"12"=>"1", "13"=>"2"}
```

When you parse a CSV, the seconds parameter (`data = Hash.new` in your code) is actually an options parameter. You can see the available options [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new):

> **:headers**
>
> If set to :first_row or true, the initial row of the CSV file will be treated as a row of headers. If set to an Array, the contents will be used as the headers. If set to a String, the String is run through a call of ::parse_line with the same :col_sep, :row_sep, and :quote_char as this instance to produce an Array of headers. This setting causes #shift to return rows as CSV::Row objects instead of Arrays and #read to return CSV::Table objects instead of an Array of Arrays.

When passing `headers: true` - values are parsed into a `Row` object, where they can be accessed by name.

Comment: But now I would like to get 12 if I use uuid[0] and 13 if I use uuid[2] how can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirement - what is `uuid[0]`?

Comment: So I checked the whole project again, and I would like to get a hash like in the updated post

Comment: So it worked now, but there are dublicate id's as values in the hash. Is there the possibility to check if there's a dublicate? for example id => 1,1,1,2,2,2 goes as id => 1,2

Comment: @aha364636 sure there is. I suggest you ask a new question, with all the relevant data, and the expected results, and you'll get your response.